# React Native TextInput setState() hides keyboard

Tags: react-native

Please check on the snack link, 
https://snack.expo.io/@banid/textinput
The TextInput on the filter view(shows when the button is pressed) hides keyboard when ever I call setState(). I call setState to update the value of TextInput. Bcause of this I can't type continuously on the TextInput. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?? Thank you

Comment: I am able to type it in my phone.

Comment: I have edited question and the snack, if you don't mind can you check once more please? @pritesh

Comment: yes it is happening now

Comment: Do you know any workaround??

Comment: It's weird though, it should not happen this way.

Comment: yeah, it's weird, can't find any solution, don't know what to do

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a **new (anonymous) function** that renders the header of the FlatList on every update

> `<FlatList  .... ListHeaderComponent={() => this.showHeader()} />`

So a new TextInput is being created instead of updating the existing one.

**Solution**:

change `ListHeaderComponent={() => this.showHeader()}`

to `ListHeaderComponent={this.showHeader}` as ListHeaderComponent can be a function

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent

Similar Issue:
https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/559

Comment: Thank you @Haythem Farhat, now it's working as expected

Answer (score 0):

It seems the focus is being removed from the TextInput after every setState, here's a work around you can use:

Change

```
this.setState({
    filterSearchText: text,
    data: newData,
});
```

To

```
this.setState({
    filterSearchText: text,
    data: newData,
}, () => {
    this.searchInput.focus();
});
```

What this does is it brings back the focus to searchInput after a setState is called

Comment: Thankyou @Raphael Estrada. It works, but when a charcter is typed the keyboard is flashing.  ie, it hides and re-appears. User experience will become poor