# How to fix keyboard error hiding react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, expo, keyboard-events

I have a TextInput inside an Animated.View, which is only displayed when clicked on a given TouchableOpacity.
The problem happens when I type in this TextInput, the keyboard hides and appears when you click on each key.
I noticed that this happens when I apply the attributes' value = {text} onChangeText = {setText} to TextInput.
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just follow the doc to set input text [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-text-input)

And it may works fine.

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

export default function PizzaTranslator() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  return (
    <View style={{padding: 10}}>
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40}}
        placeholder="Type here to translate!"
        onChangeText={text => setText(text)}
        defaultValue={text}
      />
      <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
        {text.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' ')}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with TextInput in FlatList Footer,
and this discussion can also help people

[React Native TextInput setState() hides keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56180263/react-native-textinput-setstate-hides-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should assign value. let it be. just setState on onChangeText.